# Escaping slashes in bash (awk)

Tags: bash, shell, date, awk, sed

Trying to grab a line and all following lines from an Apache log file I'm hoping to simplify the following:

```
# Convert epoch to format used in log file
gtime=$(date -d @$etime +"%d/%b/%Y:%T")  # "17/Nov/2015:16:36:45"
# Escape the slashes
g_tim=$(echo $gtime | sed 's/\//\\\//g') # "17\/Nov\/2015:16:36:45"
# Grab 
lines=$(awk '/$g_tim/,0' access.log)
```

It would be nicer if I didn't have to use two variables for this and I'm sure I'm committing various other sins to boot.

Sample lines of log file:

```
djerk.nl:80 79.134.133.108 - - [17/Nov/2015:18:51:52 +0100] "GET /wordpress/2015/null HTTP/1.1" 103 16544 "http://www.djerk.nl/wordpress/2015/cisco-lacp-config-for-aruba-ap" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"
djerk.nl:80 92.27.44.117 - - [17/Nov/2015:18:52:28 +0100] "GET /djerk_nl.pac HTTP/1.1" 403 1147 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Must have been too late last night for me to notice the edit button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments it sounds like you don't REALLY want to `grab a line and all following lines` but instead you want to print all lines starting on or after a given timestamp. That would be:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[][ /:]+"; mths="JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec" }
f { print; next }
{ logTime = sprintf("%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d",$8,(match(mths,$7)+2)/3,$6,$9,$10,$11) }
logTime >= tgtTime { f=1 }

$ awk -v tgtTime="$(date -d @"$etime" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")" -f tst.awk file
```

Note that I changed the `date` time spec args to produce the new timestamp format for comparison.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I had wrongly assumed there would not be a single second in the day without an Apache log entry against it. How wrong could I've been and in hindsight, a very bad assumption to make. Makes me wonder what is faster. Searching for a string in each line until one matches? (while != result; etime +1) << crude notation but I hope you get my drift. Or extracting the time code on each line in the log file to calculate the epoch and compare? I love your code, I have much to learn. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Just discovered that the log file also contains IPv6 addresses. These get split and cause havoc... I'm going to have to clean the data I parse but how... `wantedLines=$( awk -v tgtTime="$etime" 'BEGIN { FS="[][ /:]+"; mths="JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec" } f { print; next } { logTime = sprintf("%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d",$8,(match(mths,$7)+2)/3,$6,$9,$10,$11) } logTime >= tgtTime { f=1 }' $log_file )`

Comment: You're commenting on the wrong answer, you should be discussing your questions/needs with the author of the answer you selected as correct.

Comment: Changed the selected answer as your answer compares timestamps while the answer I'd selected earlier looks for an exact match, which I found out after I'd selected it as the best answer. Maybe I need to wait longer before I selecta best answer next time?

Comment: @dmgeurts well you probably have to make clear your mind from the beginning, since we cannot keep changing our answers every time you add a new requirement : )

Comment: @fedorqui True true, my apologies.

Answer (score 7):

You want to print everything from the line matching `17/Nov/2015:16:36:45` up to the end. Then, why don't you use this syntax?

```
awk '$0 ~ /pattern/ {f=1} f' file
```

This sets a flag when the pattern is first seen. From that moment on, `f` condition is True, so that all the lines are printed up to the end of the file.

In your case,

```
awk -v date="$(date -d @$etime +"%d/%b/%Y:%T")" '$0~date {f=1}f' file
```

Comment: Good one +1 yes I think this is what OP needs

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Pitty I found a problem with my workflow, but that's another issue altogether. I think it's going to be easier to keep track of line numbers rather than the date on each line when extracting the last 5 minutes of logged lines.

Comment: This might simplify things even further for me: `awk -v date="$(date --date='5 minutes ago' +"%d/%b/%Y:%T")" '$0~date {f=1}f' other_vhosts_access.log`. If it wasn't for the fact that from the command line the log file fails to read, I think when Apache has the file open. Also I'm curious if I will end up missing lines or with duplicates if cron doesn't manage to execute my code exactly every 300 seconds...

Comment: @dmgeurts interesting command. You may want to add -5 secs or something to compensate the possible hiccups on crontab.

Comment: @fedorqui You've got me there. Happy to research but not quite sure what you mean exactly. Excuse my crontab ignorance, don't get to use it often. More a fire and forget type of deal for me.

Comment: @dmgeurts my fault, I didn't explain it properly. What I wanted to say is that if you are worried about some ga of time being lost, you can also set the `date` variable to something with some extra seconds, like (I don't know if this is correct) `date --date='5 minutes ago + 5 sec'`.

Comment: @fedorqui Just figured out why this command doesn't work... If the date/time doesn't occur in the log file, the awk command doesn't match anything and returns nothing... I will have to read the timestamp of each line, convert it to epoch and compare if it falls in the range I'm interested in.

Comment: @fedorqui I could increase the 'window' to 305 seconds but that would surely duplicate the bytes I'm trying to count each 5 minutes and thus would skew the graphs I'm intending to feed. If I was feeding a monitoring system I could deduplicate the entries but I'm after a byte count per vhost.

Comment: @dmgeurts could you add some sample input in your question? (Or maybe a new one) Using [mktime()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) you may be able to accomplish this date comparison.

Comment: @fedorqui added 2 sample lines. Your code works perfectly, but only if the exact date is in the log file. I'll have a look at mktime() and let you know.